# How to use docker build cache when version bumping a React app?

Tags: docker, npm, caching, build, package.json

Docker doesn't use build cache when something in package.json or package-lock.json is changed, even if this is only the version number in the file, no dependencies are changed.

How can I achieve it so docker use the old build cache and skip npm install (npm ci) everytime?
I know that docker looks at the modified date of files. But package.json is not changed at all only the version number.

Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10 as builder

ARG REACT_APP_BUILD_NUMBER=X
ENV REACT_APP_BUILD_NUMBER="${REACT_APP_BUILD_NUMBER}"

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY .npmrc ./
COPY package*.json ./ 

RUN npm ci

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine

COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Answer (score 10):

Here are some solutions that should help mitigate this problem. There are trade-offs with each, but they are not necessarily mutually exclusive - they can be mixed together for better overall build performance.

---

#### Solution I: Docker BuildKit cache mounts

[Docker BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/) enables partial mitigation of this problem using the experimental [`RUN --mount=type=cache`](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/reference.md#run---mounttypecache) flag. It supports a reusable cache mount during the image build progress.

An important caveat here is that support for Docker BuildKit may vary significantly between CI/development environments. Check the documentation and the build environment to ensure it will have proper support (otherwise, it will error). Here are some requirements (but not necessarily an exhaustive list):

- The Docker daemon needs to support BuildKit (requires Docker 18.09+).
- Docker BuildKit needs to be explicitly enabled with `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` or by default from a daemon/cli configuration.
- A comment is needed at the start of the `Dockerfile` to enable experimental support: `# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.2`

Here is a sample `Dockerfile` that makes use of this feature, caching npm dependencies locally to `/usr/src/app/.npm` for reuse in subsequent builds:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.2
FROM node
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json package-lock.json /usr/src/app

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/usr/src/app/.npm \
    npm set cache /usr/src/app/.npm && \
    npm ci
```

**Notes:**

- This will cache fetched dependencies locally, but `npm` will still need to install these into the `node_modules` directory. Testing with a medium-sized project indicates that this does shave off some build time, but building `node_modules` can still be non-negligible.
- `/usr/src/app/.npm` will *not* be included in the final build, and is only available during build time (however, a lingering `.npm` directory *will* exist).
- The build cache can be cleared if needed, see [this Docker forum spost](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-delete-build-cache-buildkit-experimental/70714).
- Caching `node_modules` is not recommended. Removal of dependencies in `package.json` might not be properly propogated. Your milage may vary, if attempted.

---

#### Solution II: Install dependencies prior to copying `package.json`

On the host machine, a script extracts only the `dependencies` and `devDependencies` tags from `package.json` and copies those tags that a new file, such as `package-dependencies.json`.

E.g. `package-dependencies.json`:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
  }
}
```

In the `Dockerfile`, `COPY` the `package-dependencies.json` and `package-lock.json` and install dependencies. Then, copy the original `package.json`. Unless changes occur to `package-lock.json` or `package.json`'s `dependencies`/`devDependencies` tags, the layers will be cached and reused from a previous build, meaning minor changes to the `package.json` will not need to run `npm ci`/`npm install`.

Here is an example:

```
FROM node
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# copy dependency list and locked dependencies
COPY package-dependencies.json package-lock.json /usr/src/app/
# install dependencies
RUN npm ci
# copy over the full package configuration
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
# ...
RUN npm run build
# ...
```

Notes:

- If used mutually-exclusively, this solution will be faster than the first solution for small changes (such as a version bump), as it will not need to rerun `npm ci`.
- `package-dependencies.json` will be in the layer history. While this file would be negligible/insignificant in size, it is still "wasted space" since it is not needed in the final image.
- A quick script will be needed to generate `package-dependencies.json`. Depending on the build environments, this may be annoying to implement. Here is an example using the cli utility [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

  ```
  cat package.json | jq -S '. | with_entries(select (.key as $k | ["dependencies", "devDependencies"] | index($k)))' > package-dependencies.json
  ```

---

#### Solution III: All of the above

Solution I will enable caching npm dependencies locally for faster dependency fetching. Solution II will only ever trigger `npm ci`/`npm install` if a dependency or development dependency is updated. These solutions can used together to further accelerate build times.

Comment: Thank you, okay when I extract the dependencies into a separate file, lets say the host system will create this file, but it will be created as a new file, does docker check the contents of the file to cache or the file creation date? At the next npm install stage it will cache right hmm ok let me try this.

Comment: @webmaster It should be checking the contents of the relevant files to derive the layer cache, not the file creation or modification date.

Comment: I think I found my issue, it is because I include REACT_APP_BUILD_NUMBER at the very top to my docker image, and it is of course different each build :)